# Problems with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient, getting FTP response 421 received error

Tags: java, ftp

I have some Issue using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.
Here is my code:

```
if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    logger.debug("Fehler beim FTP verbindungsaufbau " + reply);
}
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ziel);
logger.info("....uploading...");
ftpClient.storeFile(cntKen + dateiEndung, fis);
fis.close();
logger.info("....Done!");
```

The connection to the FTP-Server is ok, but when I try to upload a file to this FTP-Server I receive a `FTP response 421 received` error message.
With the `ftpClient.storeFile(cntKen + dateiEndung, fis)` line.

The same code is working with others FTP-Servers, so I am not sure, it is a problem with the code or with some configuration of the ftp server itself.

Any ideas?

Edit: While i read for more informations. The error seams to occour when the server allows only 1 connection at the same time.
Maybe the lib make more than 1 connection?

Comment: Can you upload the same file to the same FTP path using any standalone FTP client running from the same machine as your Java code? Show us its log file. + Do you have an access to server-side FTP log file? Show us.

Comment: No thats the problem. The file is produced with a automatic process. (Its an data export) So i cannot test it with the same file with other clients. The FTP-Server is a customer FTP I dont have access to the log. But I requested them from the customer.

Comment: That's a lame excuse. So take a copy of the previous process and try to upload that.

Comment: As i explained, if it would be so easy i have done this already. The file is only temp while the process is uploaded existing.

Comment: Can you upload any file to that path on the FTP server?

Comment: Also, what is the error message that you receive with the 421 code?

Comment: With other clients yes. I was able to test the original file in the meanwhile, too. Its working with the linux ftp shell and ftp put, too. The Error could have more than one reason. https://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10142.aspx The complete error the java software received is "FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection."

Comment: What does `getReplyString()` return?

Comment: Okay , the reply String is : 421 Service not available, closing control connection.

Comment: Show us log file for *"Its working with the linux ftp shell and ftp put, too"*.

Comment: In the meanwhile i was able to solve the problem. Here if someone else has this problem, i write the solution below. however Thx Martin for help

Comment: The Solution is pretty simple. The error means, the ftp server disconneted you since the connect for some reason. So the connection to the ftp server worked, but until the upload of the file, the connection was lost. In this case here, because between the connection and the upload was a ilde time of 5 minutes. The FTP Server was configured to disconnect idle connections after 2 minutes. The disconnection could have some other reasons if you occour the same problem. But in fact the ftp connection was lost, and using .storeFile (or the ftp) is not responding no connection, but a 421 error code.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to close this question.

Comment: 2 ways: prevered: Optimize the software. Check if the ftp connections works, then close the connection. Open it again just in front of the upload. 2. Change FTP-Settings to disconnect idle connections to a higher value

Comment: Post it as an *answer*, please, not as a *comment*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is pretty simple. The error means, the ftp server disconneted you since the connect for some reason. So the connection to the ftp server worked, but until the upload of the file, the connection was lost. In this case here, because between the connection and the upload was a ilde time of 5 minutes. The FTP Server was configured to disconnect idle connections after 2 minutes. The disconnection could have some other reasons if you occour the same problem. But in fact the ftp connection was lost, and using .storeFile (or the ftp) is not responding no connection, but a 421 error code

Two ways for solution: 
1. prevered: Optimize the software. Check if the ftp connections works, then close the connection. Open it again just in front of the upload. 
2. Change FTP-Settings to disconnect idle connections to a higher value